# Angularjs single page and rendering/view data

Tags: angularjs

I have item list and trying to view each item in single page based on it id. I have the following app structure.

[Demo Link](http://neweb.io/demo/ang-test/)

**Items JSON file**

```
[{
    "id": "1-item",
    "name" : "1 item",
    "desc" : "..."
},
{
    "id": "2-item",
    "name" : "2 item",
    "desc" : "..."
}]
```

**Items List**

```
<div ng-controller="StoreController as store">

<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4" ng-repeat="product in store.products ng-hide="product.soldOut">

    <div class="caption">
        <h3>{{product.name}}</h3>

        <p>{{product.desc | limitTo: 100}}</p>

        <!-- ITEM ID LINK -->
        <a href="#/products/{{product.id}}" role="button">View</a>

    </div>
</div>
```

**Single item view**

```
<h1>{{product.name}}</h1>
<p>{{product.desc}}</p>
```

**ngRoute**

```
(function(){
var app = angular.module('store-routes', ['ngRoute']);

app.config(['$routeProvider',
    function($routeProvider) {

        $routeProvider
            .when('/products/:productId', {
                templateUrl: 'views/products-details.html',
                controller : 'StoreController',
                controllerAs: 'store'
            })
            .otherwise({
                redirectTo:  '/home'
            });
    }]); })();
```

**app.js**

```
(function(){
var app = angular.module('store', ['store-routes']);

app.controller('StoreController', ['$http', '$scope', function($http, $scope){
    var store = this;
    store.products = [];

    $http.get('data/products.json').success(function(data) {
        store.products = data;
    });

}]); })();
```

The issue here is nothing is rendering in the single view. The demo link is a little bit different it has a single page with ng-repeat so am looking for the right way to avoid it.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the success callback being called?

Comment: is url changed correctly?

Comment: @Nicolai yes. Each item has a correct url.

Comment: Did you add the `ng-app` directive?

Comment: @Mike yes. Even there's no errors in my console

Comment: It would be nice if you could create a jsbin demonstrating the problem.

Comment: I've added the demo link in my description. Or you can checkout it here http://neweb.io/demo/ang-test/ . Thanks